# Can someone help me install tsr workshop for sims 4

Tags: the-sims-4

When I open it up and press "create new project" it asks me something about running a path and that I can't do it and I don't know what to do about it please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's the link](http://wiki.thesimsresource.com/images/5/5c/A-Z_Creating_in_Workshop_V0.03.pdf) from the creator of the sims. I've also taken the liberty of creating a video tutorial:

I just downloaded TSR and received the same notice.

- Click on folder -> Sims 3 Base Game, click the 3 dots, it opens your PC.
- Go to your Program Files and select your version of the sims (if on a disc if using origin you must click origin), then the folder for games.
- Select your game and hit Apply

Once you do this, the 'create a new project' page will open and voila! You are on your way!